# Terraform exceeded wait attempts while taking snapshot of large EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

When taking a snapshot of a volume around 5TB I'm getting exceeded wait attempts:

```
aws_ebs_snapshot.banks_proddb_snapshot: Still creating... (9m40s elapsed)
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_ebs_snapshot.banks_proddb_snapshot: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_ebs_snapshot.banks_proddb_snapshot: ResourceNotReady: exceeded wait attempts
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: But when i'm taking snapshot second time it's succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a snapshot of that size is going to take a long time because Terraform waits for the API to return that the snap has completed.

Unfortunately the [`aws_ebs_snapshot` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_snapshot.html) times out after 10 minutes (default timeout for the AWS provider) and it doesn't provide any [timeout](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#timeouts) configuration.

To solve this you'd need to fix this in the source to expose timeout configuration either through a pull request or raising an [issue](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_snapshot.html) on the AWS provider Github repo.

As to your comment about the snapshot succeeding the second time that is because Terraform recognises that the snapshot has been created with that name already and so has nothing to do.